# Sound operated relay

Tags: relay, sound

I am new to electronics and I can't get this simple circuit to work.

Can anyone please tell me if the circuit is drawn correctly and the values are right?

It is supposed to run on 5 to 12 volt.

I am using 10 volts  from a 7805 rigged to output 10 volts from a 12 volt battery.

[image: Sound Operated Relay]

Comment: The microphone datasheet would help. Too many kinds of microphones. Also, what do you experience with the circuit? Is the relay stuck on? Or stuck off? The resistor values also seem wrong to me, besides the topology being a bit off, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I just have a few small two pin  mics with no markings . So have no clue what to look up .  The circuit does nothing at all . No relay click . Tested relay on a battery it's fine , it's rated to pull in and hold down to  8 volts which it does .  So could you redraw the circuit with better values ?

Comment: I can't help too much without knowing details about the microphone. It looks like the circuit may be designed for an *electret* type, given the fact that the circuit is providing power via a resistor. They are small and cheap. So that also argues for it. If so and if you do NOT have an *electret*, then this probably isn't even close to what you need. Can you supply the web link you used to access this schematic?

Comment: Yes this design is for an electret microphone; R1 provides phantom power for it.  Electret microphones need to be connected with the correct polarity to work.  To the OP: do you have a multimeter?  If so try measuring the voltages at the aw points: MIC1 to R1, T1 to R4, T2 to R5, T3 to RE1 and tell us that you find

Comment: The cat has 3 inverting transistors so the relay starts on and a negative audio pulse clicks it off, or ground the base of T1 with your finger using a 10V relay.  If using a 12V relay start with 12V an move coil to emitter and 12V and Gnd T3-C for Norm off

Comment: Cat = iOS bad speller. cct.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that Tony . Frog , I have connected the mic the right way .  Solder that goes to the case is Negative , center pad is Positive . Sorry Jonk I have no clue where I found it , some time ago . I have been all over it , checked all the polarities ,  replaced the transistors , capacitors , mic , checked the relay , checked the resistors values I do have a multi meter but I'm very new at this and don't know what voltages I'm looking for . If someone could please post the circuit  with the voltages I am needing and where to test would be very helpful .

Comment: Jonk I think I got it from here maybe .  https://www.homemade-circuits.com/simplest-sound-activated-relay-switch/ . The relay needs to stay off until a sound is detected.

Comment: @Juan I don't like the design you have. It's very sensitive to ambient temperature and part variations, to name just a few, and you'd have to ticker and make a lot of measurements to get the design functional. And I don't want to write a HeathKit manual for you. Too much work. But the basic idea of the schematic is to power the elecret (0.5 mA is typical, implying R1=15k) and to assume that T1 is "on" by whatever gets through R2 and R3 to its base, pulling T2 off and thereby also T3 off, with the relay not-engaged.

Comment: @Juan Electrets often "want" about \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$ and need about \$2\:\text{V}\$ of headroom. So you are supposed to know this (or find it in the datasheet) and then compute \$R_1=\frac{10\:\text{V}-2\:\text{V}}{500\:\mu\text{A}}=16\:\text{k}\Omega\$. That's just for starters. What you have there in \$R_1\$ is almost triple the current. It may be okay. But I don't have a datasheet so I cannot say. Your \$C_1\$ value seems low to me, given the grounded emitter of T1. And the T1 stage is crazy-dependent on part variation and temps. I'm uncomfortable with it.

Comment: Thanks but It's not my design . If it's a bad design can someone redesign it and post that image .  I don't understand a lot of what you are talking about . I will change R1 to 15k . The circuit is supposed to turn the relay on after it detects a sound and then stay on for a few seconds and turn off . Can anyone post a better circuit ?

Comment: It appears to me that I can't post another image in a comment so that makes things much harder .

Comment: "*Thanks but It's not my design.*" Site rules require you to credit the work of others. Hit the [edit] link and add them in. They look like [Elektor](http://elektor.com) schematics.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean . It's all too hard on this site . Just delete the whole thread .

Comment: You need to delete the whole question using the delete link, not just delete the content of the post.

Comment: Here's another solution: [stackexchange 540047](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539962/3-5mm-audio-jack-to-trigger-5v-relay/540047#540047)